# expresion regular para longitud de textbox

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Como puedo hacer una expresión regular para que valide que en el textbox introduzca un máximo de 19 dígitos y un mínimo de 15?

lo que tengo es esta ER pero creo que esta mal

```
var expreg = /^([0-9])*{0,25}$/;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu Expresión esta mal en el `*`.

Entonces tu expresión debería quedar así:

```
var expreg = "^([0-9]){15,19}$";
```

Lo que hace el `*` tomar ningún valor a infinito, entonces si quieres un mínimo y un máximo lo especificas en `{min,max}`

Te dejo esta [web de regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) para validación de expresiones regulares y esta [otra web de regex101](https://regex101.com/) más completa que comento @DanielFaro.

Comment: Otra web muy util es esta https://regex101.com/ Que ademas te explica lo que estás expresiones que vas haciendo.

Comment: La respuesta está perfecta, y se puede simplificar eliminando el grupo, que no parecería tener una función en este caso --> `^\d{15,19}$`